# Quest for a good xen single ip routing config with port forwarding

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, router, gateway, xen

I've been running Xen on Debian 8 at home for a couple of year in bridged mode , mostly to try PCI passthrough capabilities for gaming and still having local linux envs at reach. I've started building xen on a regular basis, from 4.2 unstable to 4.5.1 theses days, and i'm eager to try qxl accelerated drivers in 4.6 right after this summer.

But today, my problems are far away from passthrough. I've got this dedicated server rented since months, it only has a single IP and i've never sucessfully managed to setup vm's internal network config. A lot of scripts i've found on the web are for inferiors versions of xen, and networking & vif scripts changed quite a bit.

All I want is a clean way to get my VM's get adressed either based on MAC adress or statically into the 192.168.88.0/24 subnet, and being able to 
forward a list of ports (tcp or udp) toward specific vm's

So here are my config files :

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto dummy0
iface dummy0 inet manual
        pre-up ifconfig $IFACE up
        post-down ifconfig $IFACE down

auto xenbr0
iface xenbr0 inet static
        bridge_ports dummy0
        address 192.168.88.254
        broadcast 192.168.88.255
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        bridge_maxwait 0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
```

netstat -rn

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         62.210.115.1    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
62.210.115.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.88.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 xenbr0
```

iptables -L && iptables -t nat -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             PHYSDEV match --physdev-out vif1.0 --physdev-is-bridged
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             PHYSDEV match --physdev-in vif1.0 --physdev-is-bridged udp spt:bootpc dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             PHYSDEV match --physdev-out vif1.0 --physdev-is-bridged
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.88.2         anywhere             PHYSDEV match --physdev-in vif1.0 --physdev-is-bridged

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

--

Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:2222 to:192.168.88.2:22
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8888 to:192.168.88.2:80

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

/etc/network/interfaces [domU]

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
        address 192.168.88.2
        broadcast 192.168.88.255
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.88.254
```

For networking script in xen, i've created a copy of the vif-bridge script and i've added 2 lines into it to use a small script that handle iptables rules (found on the internet, and probably incomplete iptable rules)

/etc/xen/script/portmapper.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
netdev='eth0' 
# {'domU'_ip:[(domU_port, dom0port, ['tcp'|'udp']), (domU_port, dom0port), ..}
# 3rd param - protocol is optional - if not specified, tcp is default
portmap={'192.168.88.2': [(22, 2222), (80, 8888)],
        '192.168.88.3': [(8081, 10001), (22, 10002)],
        '192.168.88.4': [(6697, 6697)],
        }

# do not edit below this line
ip_tables_proto='iptables -%s PREROUTING -t nat -p %s -i %s --dport %d -j DNAT --to %s:%d\n'
import sys
is_delete=False
def usage():
    print >>sys.stderr, 'Usage: %s [-d] domU_ip' % sys.argv[0]
    sys.exit(1)
def is_ip(adr):
    ip_list=adr.split('.')
    if len(ip_list)!=4:
        usage()
    for i in ip_list:
        try:
            if int(i)>255 or int(i)<0:
                usage()
        except ValueError:
            usage()

args_no=len(sys.argv)

if args_no==3:
    if sys.argv[1]=='-d':
        is_delete=True
    ip=sys.argv[2]
    is_ip(ip)
elif args_no==2:

    ip=sys.argv[1]
    is_ip(ip)
else:
    usage()

if is_delete:
    action="D"
else:
    action="A"

mapping=portmap.get(ip, [])
cmds=''
for port_map in mapping:
    if len(port_map)==3 and port_map[2] in ('tcp', 'udp'):
        from_port, to_port, proto=port_map
    elif len(port_map)==2:
        from_port, to_port=port_map
        proto='tcp'
    cmds+=ip_tables_proto % (action, proto, netdev, to_port, ip, from_port)

import os
os.system(cmds)
```

/etc/xen/scripts/vif-bridge-nat

```
#!/bin/bash
#============================================================================
# ${XEN_SCRIPT_DIR}/vif-bridge-nat
# Script for configuring a vif in bridged mode.
#
# Usage:
# vif-bridge (add|remove|online|offline)
#
# Environment vars:
# vif         vif interface name (required).
# XENBUS_PATH path to this device's details in the XenStore (required).
#
# Read from the store:
# bridge  bridge to add the vif to (optional).  Defaults to searching for the
#         bridge itself.
# ip      list of IP networks for the vif, space-separated (optional).
#
# up:
# Enslaves the vif interface to the bridge and adds iptables rules
# for its ip addresses (if any).
#
# down:
# Removes the vif interface from the bridge and removes the iptables
# rules for its ip addresses (if any).
#============================================================================

dir=$(dirname "$0")
. "$dir/vif-common.sh"

bridge=${bridge:-}
bridge=$(xenstore_read_default "$XENBUS_PATH/bridge" "$bridge")

ip=${ip:-}

if [ -z "$bridge" ]
then
  bridge=$(brctl show | awk 'NR==2{print$1}')

  if [ -z "$bridge" ]
  then
     fatal "Could not find bridge, and none was specified"
  fi
else
  #
  # Old style bridge setup with netloop, used to have a bridge name
  # of xenbrX, enslaving pethX and vif0.X, and then configuring
  # eth0.
  #
  # New style bridge setup does not use netloop, so the bridge name
  # is ethX and the physical device is enslaved pethX
  #
  # So if...
  #
  #   - User asks for xenbrX
  #   - AND xenbrX doesn't exist
  #   - AND there is a ethX device which is a bridge
  #
  # ..then we translate xenbrX to ethX
  #
  # This lets old config files work without modification
  #
  if [ ! -e "/sys/class/net/$bridge" ] && [ -z "${bridge##xenbr*}" ]
  then
     if [ -e "/sys/class/net/eth${bridge#xenbr}/bridge" ]
     then
        bridge="eth${bridge#xenbr}"
     fi
  fi
fi

RET=0
ip link show dev $bridge 1>/dev/null 2>&1 || RET=1
if [ "$RET" -eq 1 ]
then
    fatal "Could not find bridge device $bridge"
fi

case "$command" in
    online)
        setup_virtual_bridge_port "$dev"
        set_mtu $bridge $dev
        add_to_bridge "$bridge" "$dev"
        $dir/portmap.py $ip
        ;;

    offline)
        do_without_error brctl delif "$bridge" "$dev"
        do_without_error ifconfig "$dev" down
        $dir/portmap.py -d $ip
        ;;

    add)
        setup_virtual_bridge_port "$dev"
        set_mtu $bridge $dev
        add_to_bridge "$bridge" "$dev"
        ;;
esac

handle_iptable

call_hooks vif post

log debug "Successful vif-bridge $command for $dev, bridge $bridge."
if [ "$type_if" = vif -a "$command" = "online" ]
then
  success
fi
```

ATM, my VM's don't even have acesss to the outside. I've been playing with tcpdump, pings, and wget to try to see what's happening, and tweaking the config, managed sometimes to get request to the ouside, coming back to the dom0 and getting droped, routed on the wrong interface, not finding his way to the VM. I'm feeling like i'm just missing sommes little pieces or screws...
I've also tried to use vif-nat with isc-dhcp-server, without any sucess. It could be usefull to be able to name the vm's and then map'em to a dns, so if you have any informations on this idea.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly is the problem? For example, show one specific connection attempt that's failing, say precisely what you want to happen and what is happenning.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, i was just missing 2 iptables lines, here is what i was missing

```
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface xenbr0 -j ACCEPT
```

I've put this in my /etc/rc.local so it's get executed right after startup and only once (i've put it in /etc/network/interfaces at first, but rules get multiplicated for each vm)

My script for port-forwarding do it's job, so ports get mapped correctly, rules are added uppon vm creation and removed when destroyed.

I'll probably take a deeper look into my network rules cause i doubt they are really perfect, but it does the job.